# Symfony 4: redefining security.token_storage service

Tags: symfony

I have an application that was born many years ago with Symfony 2.0 and is currently running in production with Symfony 2.8, so I'm trying to migrate it to something newer.
I had redefined the service security.token_storage with a class of mine that extends the original class (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage) adding one method. It's working since a long time.
But when I try to run the application in Symfony 4.4, this does not work anymore. The storage object should contain the security token, but when I call getToken() looks like the token is not there and I get null. Having defined access_control on login page in security.yaml with IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY role, this leads to an infinite loop on login page, because the token is missing, so Symfony doesn't acknowledge its anonymous user role.
If I remove my service override, everything works.
Any idea on what's going wrong? I see the TokenStorage class has now an initializer that it didn't have before, but I cannot understand what it does and how this can affect its behaviour.

This is my class

```
class TokenStorage extends SymfonyTokenStorage
{
    public function isHistoryDisableQualified()
    {
        if ($this->getToken() === null || $this->getToken()->getUser() === null) return false;
        return $this->getToken()->getUser()->hasRole(Roles::NO_HISTORY);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the class?

Comment: There is an Edit button in the lower left corner under your question.  Use it to update your question with code.  I should perhaps add that a voter might be a better place for this sort of functionality.

Comment: @Cerad it's quite complicated. For more than one reason I needed my entities to be aware of the user that is working (e.g. to save his id when creating one), so I injected the token storage (actually it was the security context before...) into the Doctrine Entity Manager. And, by the way, I even use it to decide if a user can make a change on an entity without it being recorded in history (that's the meaning of the method). I should really re-think the whole thing to use a voter, and I wonder if I would be able to have it available inside entities without doing something similar to this.

Comment: How did you convince Symfony to use your token class?  Used to be that you could use a parameter to override the class but that does not work anymore.  I don't understand what you are trying to do.  With a voter you could end up with something like $security->isGranted('ROLE_NO_HISTORY') in place of your method.

Comment: @Cerad be aware: I didn't redefined Token, I redefined TokenStorage. I overrode "security.token_storage" service. And by the way, it looks like it actually still works, because when I check the service class it's the one I expect it to be. The matter is it doesn't contain the Token anymore...

Comment: Token vs TokenStorage was a typo on my part.  If I had to guess you are truing to get the token in a service's constructor some place and the service is being instantiated before the token is determined.  An event listener perhaps? Maybe take a look at the priorities using bin/console debug:event-dispatcher.  Maybe just a slight tweak is all that is needed.

Comment: @Cerad looks like I solved the way you suggested. Thanks